# Измерение скорости выполнения сортировки

Tags: c#, .net

В общем захотелось начать оптимизировать что-либо, например хочу начать с оптимизации алгоритмов сортировки.

Как узнать скорость выполнения сортировки?

По сути мне нужно узнать время, за которое программа выполняется. Как это сделать? Пишу на C#

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx для работы "на месте" и https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet для исследования

Comment: вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method) все написано с примерами

Comment: Используйте `var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` и `watch.Stop();` вокруг замеряемого кода, достаточно простая и удобная штука. К примеру, если используете консоль - выводите в консоль. Подробнее тут: [Класс Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Скорость выполнения зависит от сложности алгоритма. Смотреть здесь: [Список алгоритмов сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Прямой ответ на вопрос уже дан, но есть ощущение, что нужно многое уточнить.

**Во-первых**, нет смысла заниматься оптимизацией ради оптимизации.
Вот вам цитата из [то ли Кнутта, то ли Дейкстры](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82):

> Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех (или большинства) проблем в программировании.

Оптимизация должна преследовать строго определённые цели - улучшить производительность приложения в строго определённое количество раз (определяется нуждами пользователя) в строго определённых местах, в которых текущая производительность ниже той, которая необходима пользователю приложения. Реалии таковы, что оптимизацию можно производить тысячью разных способов: смена алгоритма, смена структур данных, смена средств языка, смена языка и так далее. Предела совершенству нет, поэтому любая оптимизация без чёткого запроса пользователя - это время, потраченное впустую. Если в приложении не возникает заметных провисаний, которые мешают приложению выполнять бизнес-функции, то никакая оптимизация в действительности не нужна.

**Во-вторых**, что касается оптимизаций в .Net. Для 90% *хорошего* кода оптимизации не нужны вовсе. Из оставшихся 10% в 90% случаев потребуется только оптимизация алгоритма. В оставшихся 10% от 10% могут потребоваться различные хаки, специфичные структуры данных и так далее. К последней категории относятся такие нагруженные продукты с большим мемори траффиком, как компиляторы, ReSharper и ему подобные вещи. Проводя оптимизацию через использование специфичных средств языка и структур данных, вы **неизбежно снижаете сопровождаемость продукта**. И тут естественно встает вопрос поиска баланса между читаемостью кода и выигрышем в производительности.

**В-третьих**, чтобы заниматься оптимизацией в .Net, нужно понимать, как работает компилятор, как работает Jit, нужно понимать, что разные версия Jit'а делают различные оптимизации вашего кода и ваш супер твик, который работает быстрее на вашей системе, в конечном счете под другой версией Jit'а может работать медленнее. Различные гениальные советы, которые тут и там всплывают в интернете, типа:

- Никогда не используйте `foreach`, `for` - быстрее.
- Вместо `List<>` используйте массивы, они быстрее
- Не пользуйтесь `Linq`, он медленный
- Разматывайте циклы (имеется в виду, например, возведение в степень, кратную 4, где в каждоё итерации происходит `a *= b` 4 раза)

это всё от лукавого, ибо `foreach`, `List` и `Linq` достаточно быстры в подавляющем большинстве случаев, а извращения, вроде разматывания циклов, могут убить оптимизацию компилятора, который и без вас бы мог этот цикл размотать.

**В-четвёртых**, заниматься бенчмаркингом в .Net сложно *корректно* по тем же причинам, что озвучены выше для занятия оптимизацией. Работа разных версий Jit, необходимость "прогревать" метод перед бенчмарком, особенности работы сборщика мусора и так далее - всё это осложняет получение честных данных замеров. Золотым стандартом в этой области является использование [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) - крутейшей библиотеки для проведения бенчмарков, автором которой является Андрей Акиньшин из JetBrains, собственно, я так понимаю, продукт был написан для внутреннего пользования и в частности для разработки ReSharper. И даже этим фреймворком нужно пользоваться с головой.

Очень советую посмотреть [вот это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvuwt1keVtU), в котором Андрей сам рассказывает о BenchmarkDotNet и проблемах замеров времени в .Net.

Также советую посмотреть [совсем недавний доклад Сергея Теплякова](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHLnzjuurvQ) на тему паттернов оптимизации в .Net приложениях.

В заключение хочу сказать, что если ваша цель - просто реализовать несколько алгоритмов сортировки и сравнить их производительность на разных наборах данных - то использование `Stopwatch` может дать вам вполне неплохие результаты в рамках исследовательской задачи. Но если вопрос задан в контексте коммерческой разработки ПО, то тут уже появляется множество нюансов, касающихся целесообразности и корректности проводимых оптимизаций.

Comment: Хуже того, размотка циклов на современных процессорах может оказаться пессимизацией: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0008.2/0171.html

Comment: В-нулевых, преждевременная _пессимизация_ - корень всех тормозов в программировании.

Comment: Если прочитать ответ по диагонали, то глаз зацепится за четыре «гениальных совета». Ок, подумает читатель, пойду заменять for на foreach. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и правда, поправил.

Comment: "необходимость прогревать метод перед бенчмарком". Плюсую, но хочу заметить, что для задач реального времени типа обработки сигналов в этом самом реальном времени будет играть роль именно скорость "непрогретого" метода.

Answer (score 4):

Для точных измерений с прогоном по несколько раз и вычичления среднего времени выполнения кода следует воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, наподобие [BenchmarkDotNET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/), у них отличное API, при чём удобное, в том числе, и для встраивания Ваших бенчмарков прямо в Ваши тесты. 
Более простой способ измерения скорости выполнения без использования стандартных библиотек - класс [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) из пространства имён `System.Diagnostics`. Измерять скорость выполнения кода можно таким образом:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

stopwatch.Start();

//Замените на измеряемый код:
Thread.Sleep(1800);

stopwatch.Stop();

//Время, за которое выполнился Ваш код будет храниться в этой переменной:
var elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Значение переменной `elapsedTime` можете выводить на консоль или в Trace вашего теста - как угодно. Опять же, если нужно замерять скорость выполнения кода во многих местах, при чём регулярно, можно создать обёртку класса `Stopwatch` для выполнения измерений с использованием `IDisposable` и помещать измеряемый код в блок `using`.